# Send Angular Form via email

Tags: angular, cgi-bin, formmail

I have a simple static Angular website and I have a contact form in one of the pages.

I know that Angular has no way of submitting a form via email like the olden days.  I am also aware of third party services which are able to send emails for you.  However, I didn't come across any free third party service to do this task.  Also, is there maybe a way of using the cgi-bin to send my form to an email address?

This website is not a commercial website, and therefore the budgets are limited.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's service i use regularly that allows you to send email from front end only, However it only allows you to send limited emails per month

Here's how you can integrate it, Let me know if you face any problem with it:

[Email JS](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/angular/)

Answer (score 0):

Our Hosted Forms service will work for you and we have a free plan.

Also, it doesn't just send email (which is unreliable), but keeps a copy of the form submissions so that you can read them in your account.

I hope that helps.

cheers,
Russell Robinson
Author of Tectite FormMail.